# An $L^2$ bound for a function of the form $w(x)=|x|^{-1} - (g^2*|x|^{-1}*g^2)(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, mathematical-physics, lp-spaces

It is stated in the paper [E. Lieb  and H.-T. Yau,  *The Chandrasekhar Theory of Stellar Collapse as the Limit of Quantum Mechanics* Commun. Math. Phys. 112, 147-174 (1987)] 
that this function is "clearly" in $L^2$:

> $w(x)=|x|^{-1} - (g^2*|x|^{-1}*g^2)(x)$
>
> with  $g(x)=\xi^{3/4} \exp(-\pi \xi x^2/2)$ and therefore $||g||_2 =1$.

It's bound is supposed to be $|| w||_2 \leq \xi^{-1/4} \sqrt{\frac{32}{3 \pi^{1/2}}}$.

By evaluating the spherical parts I got to the point that

> $0 \leq w(x) \leq \int d^3a \int d^3 b\ \ g^2 (a) g^2 (b)\left[ \frac{1}{|x|} - \textrm{min}\left\{ \frac{1}{|x|}, \frac{1}{|a|}, \frac{1}{|b|}  \right\}\right]$

I can see that it's in $L^2$, but every estimate I make is too rough to yield the above bound. Any ideas on some good estimates or to evaluate it exactly?

Comment: (with H.-T. Yau) The Chandrasekhar Theory of Stellar Collapse as the Limit of Quantum Mechanics, Commun. Math. Phys. 112, 147-174 (1987).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how Prof. Lieb got that particular bound, but if I'm not mistaken we can evaluate the norm exactly!  I'll try to write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $\xi = 1$.  Here $x$ and $y$ will denote elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Now we go all the way back to Isaac Newton!  We have the following integral over the surface of the sphere (the "shell theorem" from classical mechanics),
$$\int_{\mathbb{S}^2} |r \omega - x | ^{-1} d\omega = 4\pi\min(r^{-1}, |x|^{-1}).$$

This gives a striking identity for the convolution of $|x|^{-1}$ with a radially symmetric function $\rho(x) = \rho(|x|)$.
$$\left(|x|^{-1} \ast \rho(x) \right)(x) = 4\pi \int_0^\infty \min(r^{-1},|x|^{-1}) \rho(r) r^2 \,dr.$$
Note that this particular identity works only in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but there is a more general version that you can find in Lieb and Loss "Analysis", page 249.

Now let
$$\rho(x) = (g^2 \ast g^2)(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \exp\left(-\frac{\pi |x|^2}{2}\right).$$The operation of convolution is commutative and associative, so we have
$$w(x) = |x|^{-1} - (|x|^{-1} \ast \rho)(x) = \int_\mathbb{R^3} |x|^{-1} \rho(y) \,d^3y - \int_\mathbb{R^3} |x-y|^{-1} \rho(y) \,d^3y \\= 4\pi \int_0^\infty |x|^{-1} \rho(r)r^2\,dr - 4\pi \int_0^\infty \min(r^{-1}, |x|^{-1}) \rho(r)r^2 \,dr = 4\pi \int_{|x|}^\infty (|x|^{-1}-r^{-1}) \rho(r)r^2 \,dr.$$

Now we can rewrite $w(x)$ in terms of complementary error function "erfc",
$$w(x) = \frac{\operatorname{erfc}(|x|\sqrt{\pi/2})}{|x|}.$$

Thus we have
$$\|w\|_2^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |w(x)|^2 \,d^3x = \int_0^\infty 4\pi \operatorname{erfc}(r\sqrt{\pi/2})^2 \,dr = 8(\sqrt{2}-1).$$
So we conclude with an exact value for the $L^2$-norm of $w$,
$$\|w\|_2 = \sqrt{8(\sqrt{2}-1)}.$$

Comment: cool, one more question: How did you evaluate the erfc² in the last integral?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha!!

Comment: it was a double part int